# Settings for blueimp? Not displaying full screen image

Tags: 2sxc

2sxc newby. I just installed version 8 in DNN 8.02, added the module to a page, added the blueimp app, but when I click on an image it does not go full screen - nothing happens. It does go if I go to the 2sxc demo page. Is there another setting I need? Hovering over the image shows a url that looks like it should work...

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here - possible some kind of javascript issues. Can you be more precise about the 2sxc version? also please check if you're getting JS errors (http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/debugging-javascript-errors-with-a-modern-browser-and-f12-(200))